# Django "You have unapplied migrations". Which ones?

Tags: django, django-migrations

Django `runserver` complains:

```
You have unapplied migrations; 
your app may not work properly until they are applied. 
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

How can I find out which migrations are unapplied without running migrate?

Comment: One way to do this is to look at the django_migrations table in the DB and check which ones are applied. But I wasn't sure if there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you're on 1.7, use `python manage.py migrate --list`. ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---list))

If you're on 1.8 or above, use `python manage.py showmigrations --list`. ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations))

In either case, there will be an **[X]** to show which migrations have been applied.

Answer (score 24):

A minor modification on Kevin's answer using grep, to **only show unapplied migrations**:

Django 1.7:

```
python manage.py migrate --list | grep -v '\[X\]'
```

Django 1.8 and above:

```
python manage.py showmigrations --list | grep -v '\[X\]'
```

Edited after ngoue's comment. Nice catch. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Nope, because the `-v` option tells the `grep`  command to show the lines that do not contain `[x]`

Comment: Should actually be `grep -v '\[X\]'` otherwise it will exclude any migrations that have an "X" in the name.

Comment: You are indeed right ngoue. Thanks for the point. I did a quick check and a migration with an X in the name would be ignored, which is certainly not desirable. However, I guess that this rarely happens, since autogenerated migrations have lowercase names by default, for instance. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: with `grep -v '\[X\]` you'll also get application names. Use `... | grep "\[\ \]"` to show _only_ unapplied migration

Answer (score 15):

You can see a list of just the unapplied migrations with the `--plan` option of the `migrate` command:

```
python manage.py migrate --plan
```

It was introduced in Django 2.2 and is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-plan).

Answer (score 2):

after using this command :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

you get the same error:  **You have un-applied migrations;**

simple way to solve this error is  to
go to your project directory search for your database directory that is created after command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

in my case db created was **db.sqlite3** 
just delete that file and go to your terminal
and use `manage.py makemigrations` followed by `manage.py migrate` .

this worked for me . All the best

Comment: This will delete all your existing data and tables, should not do this if you aren't 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Once you run the migration command (`python manage.py migrate`) its always generates an `auto_migration.py` file in that specific app.

Also the same file you will be able to see it in your database. If that file is missing in your DB then your project will complain about "un-applied migrations".

So just go to your db and manually create an entry for `auto_migration.py`.